# warning deleting array, in load file function

Tags: c++, crash, warnings

I've got troubles loading a file into memory, my compiler warns me about something I do not grasp. What's the matter?

```
C:\Users\Caroline\Desktop\Prog\literature.cpp:236:15: warning: deleting array 'char chbuffer [(((sizetype)((ssizetype)fsize)) + 1)]' [enabled by default]
```

**function :**

```
bool loadfile(string & buffer, const char fpath[])
{
    ifstream file(fpath, ios::binary);
    if(!file) return false;
    file.seekg(0, ios::end);
    long fsize = file.tellg();
    file.clear();
    file.seekg(0);
    char chbuffer[fsize + 1];
    file.read(chbuffer, fsize);
    buffer = chbuffer;
    delete [] chbuffer;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: If there's no `new`, there shall be no `delete`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot `delete` an automatically allocated array. Remove the `delete [] chbuffer;` statement.

In general, `delete` is only used when paired with `new`. You could have allocated `chbuffer` like this:

```
char *chbuffer = new char[fsize + 1];
```

in which case you *would* want to use `delete [] chbuffer`.

Comment: haha thank you, i'm very tired. how has it been working so far? we may allocate dynamically whithout "new"?

Comment: @nomatchland if ``fsize`` is not a compile-time constant, then the only way for it to compile is with a non-standard extension.

Comment: @nomatchland an extension to the language. Some compilers have extensions that break the rules laid out by the c++ standard.

Comment: thank you Juan, I see now. Rules should be made not to be broken.